# what are the poles of (tanz)/z

Tags: complex-analysis

What are the poles of tanz/z and what is the best way to find them? I know what the answer is and the way I found it was to rewrite tanz/z as sinz/cosz and got 0 and (2n+1)pi/2. The one thing I am curious about though is another method where we rewrite tanz as a power series centered at 0, we get x + (x^3)/3+(x^5)/15...  by Taylor expansion and if we divide by z, the first term will always be 1. So that means we don't have any poles since nothing we plug in gives us any 0 or discontinuity, but that is impossible since these are just different ways of expressing the same thing, so what went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series for $\frac{\tan z}z$ is only correct within some neighbourhood of the point it is expanded about. There will be, by definition, no poles within that neighbourhood. But there may be poles outside it.

Comment: Does $\frac{\tan(z)}{z} = \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \cos(z)$ as OP suggested help with anything?

Comment: if we split tan into sin and cos, then we easily get the correct answer. i was just curious about splitting up tan using other ways to see if we get the same answer. But yeah, we can't use the taylor series here since it is not defined at 0.

Comment: if we wanted to find the residue from the laurent series, is there a way to do it ?

Comment: In order to find the singularities write $\frac{\tan(z)}{z} = \frac{\sin(z)}{z \cos(z)}$ and find the zeros of the denominator. To find their orders, you should consider their limits compared with different orders.